# Ableton - exported mp3 does not include MIDI tracks

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I have a project in Ableton with some MIDI tracks and some audio tracks. They both play when I listen to the track in the Ableton, so all the tracks are turned on with proper levels.

When I export the song to AIF/MP3, however, one of the MIDI tracks is not included in the export. Some of the MIDI tracks are included in the export.

I've tried restarting several times and checking all the settings, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I had the "Output Type" set to "Ext. Out" (i.e., my system audio speakers), rather than to the Master track or the subgroup ("Instruments") that I had created.

[image: Ableton screencap showing configuration]